# bash script - how to setup a function to work with an embedded if statement

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement

I have the following working function in my bash script:

```
addMD5SUM()
{
file=$COLS2
linecount=$(wc -l $file | awk '{ print $1 }')
counter=1
while IFS='' read -r column; do
  case column in
    visitor_id)
       echo "isnull($column|| '[|]' ||";;
       updated)
       echo "isnull($column::text || '[|]' ||";;
             *)
       echo "isnull($column::text,'[null!]') || '[|]' ||";;
  esac
  if [ "$counter" -eq "$linecount" ]; then
      echo "isnull($column::text,'[null!]')) as md5sum"
  fi
  ((counter++))
done <"$file"
}
```

Where `$COL2` is a single filename:

```
COLS2="myoutputfile2.out"
```

Contents of this file would be something like:

```
visitor_id
updated
visitor_list_1
visitor_list_2
visitor_list_3
visitor_list_4
visitor_list_5
```

Other files would be similar: (i.e.)

```
visitor_id
updated
visitor_list_6
visitor_list_7
visitor_list_8
visitor_list_9
visitor_list_10
```

Now, I need to alter this function so that I have the option to have it work with **either** one of these files:

```
export COLS1="myoutputfile1.out"
export COLS2="myoutputfile2.out"
export COLS3="myoutputfile3.out"
export COLS4="myoutputfile4.out"
```

How would you do this? Would you do this as an `if-statement`? What is the best and proper way to do handle this?

Comment: Please post the example sample Input_file and expected sample output too in your post.

Comment: `linecount=$(wc -l <"$file")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the `COLSn` as a parameter to the function

```
addMD5SUM()
{
  file="$1"
  ...
}
```

then

```
addMD5SUM $COLS1
addMD5SUM $COLS2
...
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you. That makes sense and was simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use the <s>evil</s> `eval` to let Bash parse the variable for an extra pass.

```
export COLS1="myoutputfile1.out"
export COLS2="myoutputfile2.out"
export COLS3="myoutputfile3.out"
export COLS4="myoutputfile4.out"

addMD5SUM()
{
eval file=\$$1
...
```

And call the new function like

```
addMD5SUM COLS1
addMD5SUM COLS2
addMD5SUM COLS3
addMD5SUM COLS4
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the accepted answer, you can send an argument to the function but user supplied arguments shouldn't be trusted.

Since your files have a format, you could do something like below

```
file=${1:-0} # If the argument 1 is not present, assign zero to file
! [[ "${file}" =~ myoutputfile[0-9]+.out ]] || ! [ -f "${file}" ] &&
echo "Invalid parameter" && exit 1
```